# Is this function continuous or not?

Tags: calculus, continuity

is this function continuous:

$$f(x,y) = \begin{cases}
  \sqrt{1-x^2-y^2} , & x^2+y^2 < 1 \cr
  0, & x^2+y^2 \geq 1 \end{cases}$$

I think it's continuous but I don't know how to prove it.

Comment: When asking questions about continuity you need to be really careful about where the function is defined. This looks like a function $\mathbb R^2\to \mathbb R$. For example, if $x,y\gt 1$ the result is trivial, because the function is constant for those values.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

hint:

Go into polar coordinates:

$$x=r\cos t\;,\;\;y=r\sin t\implies x^2+y^2=r^2$$

and thus your question is: is the following function of $\;r\;$ continuous?:

$$f(r):=\begin{cases}\sqrt{1-r^2}&,\;\;r<1\\{}\\0&,\;\;r\ge 1\end{cases}$$

Comment: I don't see how this helps.

Comment: @Donkey_2009 DonAntonio took it down a dimension.

Comment: @Donkey_2009, I think sasha, and apparently also the OP, consider that messing with a one variable function is, at least in this case, much simpler and direct than with the original function...

Answer (score 6):

Hint:

The pieces are both defined and continuous. (To see that the first one is continuous, just note that it's made up of additions, multiplications and compositions of continuous functions. If you don't know that additions, multiplications and compositions of continuous functions are continuous, then you have another task ahead of you :) )

The only thing that remains to be seen is if these two functions actually "line up" at the break. Do they?